# Setting uniform in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, haskell, glsl

I have an uniform in the *form* of:

```
uniform float abc;
```

and I get it in Haskell code as:

```
abc <- GL.get (GL.uniformLocation program "abc")
```

How can I pass a `GLfloat` value to it?

I see from [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/OpenGL-2.12.0.0/docs/src/Graphics-Rendering-OpenGL-GL-Shaders-Uniform.html#UniformComponent) that I should probably be using `uniform1`, but that function is not exported by the module.

Every other instance:

```
instance UniformComponent a => Uniform (Vertex2 a)
instance UniformComponent a => Uniform (Vertex3 a)
instance UniformComponent a => Uniform (Vertex4 a)
instance UniformComponent a => Uniform (TexCoord1 a)
instance UniformComponent a => Uniform (TexCoord2 a)
instance UniformComponent a => Uniform (TexCoord3 a)
instance UniformComponent a => Uniform (TexCoord4 a)
instance UniformComponent a => Uniform (Normal3 a)
instance UniformComponent a => Uniform (FogCoord1 a)
instance UniformComponent a => Uniform (Color3 a)
instance UniformComponent a => Uniform (Color4 a)
instance UniformComponent a => Uniform (Index1 a)
```

does not seem to cover this simple case.

What can I do?

Comment: Ouch that's rough, looks like an API bug.  [Report it](https://github.com/haskell-opengl/OpenGL/issues), then for now I guess change your uniform to a vector and just use one component :-(

Comment: @luqui Oh, apparently [it's reported already](https://github.com/haskell-opengl/OpenGL/issues/64).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently [it's a known bug](https://github.com/haskell-opengl/OpenGL/issues/64) in the API.

A possible alternative for now is to use the `Index1` overload, which is supposed to be a color index, but works fine with simple floats.